# Overlapping buttons using inline-block

Tags: html, css

Might be an obvious solution but I can't seem to figure out why my two buttons are positioned one over-top the other (#btn-color directly on top of #btn-icon) when I want them aligned side by side.

```css
#btn-color,
#btn-icon {
  display: inline-block;
}

#btn-icon a {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 43px;
}

#btn-color a {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 20px 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d11e5d;
}
```

```html
<div id="ftr-icn-wrap" class="flex">
  <div id="btn-icon"><a href="#">professional</a></div>
  <div id="btn-color"><a href="#">Contact me</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your anchor elements are `display: inline` by default. Therefore, top and bottom padding are not respected. Change them to `display: inline-block`.

```css
#btn-color, #btn-icon {
  display: inline-block;
}

#btn-icon a {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 43px;
  display: inline-block; /* new */
}

#btn-color a {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 20px 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d11e5d;
  display: inline-block; /* new */
}
```

```html
<div id="ftr-icn-wrap" class="flex">
  <div id="btn-icon"><a href="#">professional</a></div>
  <div id="btn-color"><a href="#">Contact me</a></div>
</div>
```